# Is the form tag "<form>" meant to be inside the body tag "<body>"

Tags: html

Is the form tag "" meant to be inside the body tag ""
Sorry, this is probably a really dumb question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it belongs into the `<body>` tag
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp